# KDE: startup script doesn't work

Tags: kde, startup, touchpad

OS: Linux Slackware 14.2, GUI: KDE. I have a touchpad on my laptop and it bothers me a lot when typing, so I decided to disable it. It can be done with command:

```
bash$ synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

To do it on startup I created a script `my_startup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

And put it into the folder `~/.kde/share/autostart`. Made executable. When I open "System Settings" --- "Startup and Shutdown" --- "Autostart" it shows the script as enabled:

[image]

But it doesn't work - the toupad is enabled and I have to run the script manually every time.

What's wrong?

Comment: It might not be finding `synclient` if `PATH` isn't set at that point -- have you tried giving the complete path (`which synclient`)?

Comment: Try `synclient TouchpadOff=1 &>/tmp/login.log` to see if it does really run on login or if there are errors. BTW AFAIR I saw an option in kde config GUI to auto-disable touchpad if a mouse is plugged in, which I found useful.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Seems to all right: `bash-4.3# which synclient` --> `/usr/bin/synclient`

Comment: @rudimeier Did it, will try on the next startup. How to find this option?

Comment: Maybe https://www.linux-apps.com/content/show.php/kcm_touchpad?content=113335, Could be that such module is included by default in KDE > 5.3: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189567

Comment: Came here to suggest disabling it in the OS, permanently, but @rudimeier already showed you how.